# Google's DocumentAi feature "human in the loop" don't work anymore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

from one day to another the "human in the loop" feature didn't work anymore.  
I did the following things:

1. I created a new processor (form parser) on the Google cloud console.
2. I enabled the "human in the loop" feature for the processor on the Google cloud console. I set the confidence threshold on 100% so that every document will be sent for human review.
3. I added a specialist for "human in the loop" and opened the specialist review tool.
4. I sent a request (with a document in the request body) by a client library to the processor.
5. The response is saying: human review is "IN_PROGRESS"

But after all these steps I don't see a document anymore that have to be reviewed. Does anyone know this problem?

Comment: Hi @Armin PuranYoussef, Thanks for reporting this, I have created a public issue for this here:[issuetracker.google.com/243897398](https://issuetracker.google.com/243897398) , you can subscribe to this issue by [staring](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe) it. Further updates will be shared on the issue thread.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was reported as resolved in https://issuetracker.google.com/243897398